nuxt 3 can not read env of docker when i pass environment in compose file (runtimeConfig)
this is my nuxt.config.ts
....
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      baseURL: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
    }
  },
....

this is my dockerfile
FROM node:20

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

COPY . .

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "preview"]

and this is my dockerignore
node_modules
npm-debug*
.nuxt
.env

this is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  my-nuxt-app:
    image: h/h
    container_name: my-nuxt-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NUXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://api.example.com

when i use
docker exec -it my-nuxt-app printenv NUXT_PUBLIC_API_URL

it show https://api.example.com
but in nuxtapp: localhost:3000, tab network fetch api is: http:127.0.0.1/undefind/......
i try add command: yarn install & yarn build & yarn preview
in docker-compose.yml and it work but it is bad

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FYV5WfiWvs
It is not advised to directly pass the env value in the nuxtconfig because it ends up being hard baked on build. And once you built the value is transformed into a string and cannot be changed even if you change the .env value... Unless you rebuild again. Check the TS hint on the variable. It will suggest overriding the value in the .env as NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL="api.example.com" and setting the value in your config as
public: {
      baseURL: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
}

Here's more info.
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config
